# Can a C++ std::list iterator move past the end?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

```
for(std::list<MyClass *>::iterator it = m_currentJobs.begin(); it != m_currentJobs.end(); ++it)
{
    request = *it;
    if(request != NULL)
    {
        printf(request->status());
    }

    delete request;
    m_currentJobs.erase(it);
}
```

Is it possible for the iterator to point to some garbage data beyond the end of the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You make your iterator invalid by erasing it.

You may change your loop to:

```
std::list<MyClass *>::iterator it = m_currentJobs.begin();
while(it != m_currentJobs.end())
{
    // ...
    it = m_currentJobs.erase(it);
}
```

And to answer your question: Yes it is possible to have an invalid iterator (not limited to iterators past the end). Using these involves undefined behavior.

Comment: That makes sense, and I appreciate that it is more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

At the end of each iteration, you do this:

```
m_currentJobs.erase(it);
```

which invalidates `it`.

Immediately afterwards, you do this:

```
++it
```

which is undefined behavior if `it` is not a valid iterator.

Most likely, that is your problem.

`std::list::erase` actually returns an iterator, pointing to the element *after* the deleted one. Reset `it` to point to that, and your code should work a lot better. (Note that when this happens, you've already jumped to the next element, so you shouldn't *also* run `++it` in that iteration.)

Comment: I wonder why it sometimes worked. I suppose that is why it becomes undefined. That thread has a lot more logic in it in the code-base, so it was more difficult to detect the error. Do you think that the only time it really causes an error could be when the iterator goes past the end? I am now always taking in the returned it. If it is the end, then I break out of the for loop.